# Create Excel file from xml file using xslt in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is it possible to create Excel file using xslt transformation from xml in Java?

Comment: No this is not possible. A Excel file is either a binary file in BIFF format (`*.xls`) or a ZIP archive containing a directory structure having XMLfiles in it but other file types too. The latter is the OOXML format (`*.xlsx`) but is not only XML alone. So you could create the XML files for the `*.xlsx` using XSLT but not the whole `*.xlsx` file.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks!!